# Javascript falsy values (null, undefined, false, empty string: "" or '' and 0) and comparison(==) operator

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

When I am using any one of values(`null`, `undefined`, `false`, `''`, `0`) in a `if` statement, it is always evaluated as fallacy(`false`). Also, the negation of these values((`null`, `undefined`, `false`, `''`, `0`) in a `if` statement always evaluated as tautology(`true`).

```
 if(null){
 }else{
 }

 if(undefined){
 }else{
 }

 if(false){
 }else{
 }

 if(''){
 }else{
 }

 if(0){
 }else{
 }
```

In all the above cases, `if` statement is evaluated as `false` & `else` statement executes. 
However, when I am comparing these fallacy values with `==` operator, it is not returning `true` always. Surprisingly, it is always returning `true` values when I am comparing the negation of these values.

if double equalto (`==`) operator checks/compares for values & not strictly for types, then why:

```
null == false          // returns false

null == 0              // returns false

null == ''             // returns false
```

But,

```
!null == !false       // returns true

!null == !0           // returns true

!false == !undefined  // returns true
```

And,

```
null == undefined     // returns true

false == 0            // returns true
```

I appreciate if any one can clarify the behavior or relationship among these values(`null`, `undefined`, `false`, `''`, `0`).

Comment: [Here is the `==` operator as defined in the spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

Comment: Since nobody has mentioned it here, the double exclamation (!!, i.e. not not) can be useful.  if (!!myvariable) returns true if myvariable's value is not any value that makes it false. This is not always the same as checking if (myvariable == true).

Answer (score 17):

### A common misconception

> *"...If double equalto (`==`) operator only checks/compares for values & not for types..."*

That's an incorrect assumption, though it's often repeated by people. In reality, the `==` *does* check types, and in fact pays far more attention to the types than a `===` comparison does.

See *[Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)*.

A `==` comparison doesn't do a simple *toBoolean* conversion. Rather it walks through a somewhat complex recursive algorithm, which, after checking the types, attempts to coerce the operands to the same type if they don't match.

The type coercion that it performs is very specific to the types of the operands. A different sequence of coercions can take place for different type pairs. Usually (but not always) it ends up ultimately coercing the operands down to `number` types.

---

### Why `!`ing the operands changes things

When you manually coerce both operands using `!`, you're now doing a simple *toBoolean* conversion causing the types to match, which avoids the type coercive part of the algorithm, making it behave essentially like the *[Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)*.

So the only way to predict the outcome of a `==` comparison when the types don't match is to understand that Abstract algorithm.

---

### Don't forget about `NaN`

And FYI, there's one more "falsey" value to consider, `NaN`. Its `==` comparison will always be `false`, no matter what. Even when comparing to another `NaN` value, it'll be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined`: means a variable was declared but has no value assigned

`null`: the value of null has been assigned, which means it has no value

`false`, `''` and `0` I think you can probably work out what these mean.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is different from false (NULL is of type object and false is of type of boolean), null is different from 0 (0 is of type integer), null is also different from '' ('' is of type of string). but they are all falsy values. The ! operator negates a boolean value. If ! is used on falsy values, it results to conversion of falsy values to an object of type boolean.

Comment: Not an "*object* of type boolean", but in general yes.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My questions was - if all these values are falsy values(null, undefined, false, '', 0) and double equalto (==) operator compares values(not types) then why they returns -
null == false // returns false
null == undefined // returns true 
!null == !false //returns true

Comment: @SurajKumar, it's because the == operator converts both operands to the same type before performing the actual comparison.