# Calling String.replace on a string that ![String instance] returns true for?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Reviewing the [class-validator ValidatorConstraint](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/63e173c806bdfc879d13a0069debb73f4a757bf6/src/decorator/decorators.ts#L22) implementation and it has a section that looks like this:

```
        name = target.name;
        if (!name) // generate name if it was not given
            name = name.replace(/\.?([A-Z]+)/g, (x, y) => "_" + y.toLowerCase()).replace(/^_/, "");
```

Does the `!name` part make sense?  For example `console.log(!"")` logs true, so it could be that name is an empty string and `console.log(!undefined)` is also true.

So my hypothesis is that the code block inside the `if (!name) block will never make sense because there will never be a string to perform replacements on inside the block?

Comment: I am puzzled by your question, do you not understand how falsy values work or what? Here's a post that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206207/javascript-falsy-values-null-undefined-false-empty-string-or-and-0-a

Comment: `!name` makes sense, but using `name.replace` on falsy name doesn't ... seems like a bug

Comment: !"" would enter the if block.  Then we would try to replace parts of the string using the regular expression.  With "" there's nothing to replace ...

Comment: If u explicitly want to check for a `truthy` value, you should consider `!!! ` since, it converts all types to an appropriate boolean type

Comment: null.replace()? undefined.replace()? Sorry...

Comment: Yeah I think it's a bug ... just wanted to double check here before reporting it...but now its reported https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/221